# Data not being inserted into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am following MongoDB tutorial to test to insert a data into existing database.

This is the code I have in Python file:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

result = db.restaurants.insert_one(
    {
        "address": {
            "street": "2 Avenue",
            "zipcode": "10075",
            "building": "1480",
            "coord": [-73.9557413, 40.7720266]
        },
        "borough": "Manhattan",
        "cuisine": "Italian",
        "grades": [
            {
                "date": datetime.strptime("2014-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                "grade": "A",
                "score": 11
            },
            {
                "date": datetime.strptime("2014-01-16", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                "grade": "B",
                "score": 17
            }
        ],
        "name": "Vella",
        "restaurant_id": "41704620"
    }
)
```

And I run `python3 (filename)` on the terminal.
The result I get is:

```
2015-11-22T14:08:55.779-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53193 #41 (2 connections now open)
2015-11-22T14:09:10.243-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53195 #42 (3 connections now open)
2015-11-22T14:09:10.750-0800 I NETWORK  [conn42] end connection 127.0.0.1:53195 (2 connections now open)
```

Two connections are from using a program called robomongo which lets to see database in MongoDB. I see that connection is open and closed. But When I inspect the data from robomongo, I cannot find added data.
I did double check that name of database is `test` and name of collection is `restaurants`.
The way I imported original data set is like following:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely working. Make sure you connect to the right host and port. The script assumes to work with default settings, localhost and port 27017.

Comment: That's what I thought. But data is not made there :( My database is on default setting so localhost and port are right.